# HorizontalScrollView motion in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

In my android application, there are two HorizontalScrollViews I am using. Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hScroll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Blue" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtFriend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txtFriend"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="@string/txtList"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtWork"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="@string/txtWork"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="@string/txtPlay"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBuddies"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="@string/txtBuddies"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hScroll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listFriend"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="280dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listList"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, what I have to do is when I move 2nd horizontal scrollview (here id =hScroll2) then Simultaneously my 1st horizontal scroll view must be moved. Here is my java code.

```
 hs2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int scrollX = v.getScrollX();
                int curX = scrollX;
                hs1.scrollBy(scrollX, 0);
                return false;

            }
        });
```

But, when I am moving 2nd scroll view horizontally from Left to Right, 1st scroll view is moving with it at same time, but when I am moving 2nd back to its position(Right to Left), then 1st one is not moving. It sticks on new position. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I come with a small workaround for such needs. I have implemented it in one of my projects and it works fine:

make a custom HorizontalScrollView and a ScrollListener interface to get the results You want:

### ExampleScrollView.java

```
    public class ExampleScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;

/**
 * constructor
 * 
 * @param context
 *            current contex
 * @param attrs
 *            AttributeSet
 * @param defStyle
 *            style
 */
public ExampleScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * constructor
 * 
 * @param context
 *            current contex
 * @param attrs
 *            AttributeSet
 */
public ExampleScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

/**
 * constructor
 * 
 * @param context
 *            current context
 */
public ExampleScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    if (scrollViewListener != null) {
        scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

}

/**
 * sets the scrollViewListener
 * 
 * @param scrollViewListener
 */
public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
    this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
}

 }
```

### ScollViewListener Interface

```
    public interface ScrollViewListener {

void onScrollChanged(ExampleScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx,
        int oldy);

    }
```

### Use the ScrollView

```
    private ExampleScrollView mScrollViewOne;
    private ExampleScrollView mScrollViewTwo;

    mScrollOne = (ExampleScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_one);
    mScrollOne.setScrollViewListener(new ScrollViewListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(ExampleScrollView scrollView, int x,
                int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mScrollTwo.scrollTo(x, y);
        }

    });

    mScrollTwo = (ExampleScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_two);
    mScrollTwo.setScrollViewListener(new ScrollViewListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(ExampleScrollView scrollView, int x,
                int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mScrollOne.scrollTo(x, y);
            }

    });
```

### Usage in layout.xml

```
     <com.yourpackage.ExampleScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
```

I hope this helps a little bit...

Comment: Thank you for your help... I am going to implement it...If any doubt will be there, I will ask you...

Comment: Thank you so much.