# OnScrollListener Horizontall Scroll View error

Tags: java, android, scrollbar

I'm trying to Implement a scrollListener to get an event on scroll of HorizontallScrollview, which android does not provide, so i found out another way to implement this
using this link

[listening to scroll events horizontalscrollview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461991/listening-to-scroll-events-horizontalscrollview-android)

> -->create a Class that extends horizontall scroll view
>
> --> override on scroll changed method

But when i create an object of my class in my activity class it gives error.

Logcat output attached.

Pls. Help. I'm doing this for the first time.

**code:
XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.gridTest.myHorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_thumb"
        android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_track"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="18"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/text1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
    </com.example.gridTest.myHorizontalScrollView>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code:
MainActivity**

```
package com.example.gridtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    GridLayout  grid    =   null;
    ViewGroup   vg      =   null;
        myHorizontalScrollView hsvw =   null;
    SeekBar seekBar         =   null;
    Display myDisplay       =   null;
    int width           =   0;
    TextView  text1 =   null;
    int max = 954;
    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        grid    =   (GridLayout) (findViewById(R.id.grid));
        hsvw    =   (myHorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
           //error occur here..

                seekBar =   (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        myDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        width = myDisplay.getWidth();
        text1=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.text1));
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
       
        text1.getWidth();
        text1.getHeight();
   
}
```

**myHorizontalScrollView.java**

```
package com.example.gridtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class myHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView{

    public myHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Scrolling", "X from ["+oldl+"] to ["+l+"]");
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

}
```

Log Cat OutPut:

```
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gridtest/com.example.gridtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.gridTest.myHorizontalScrollView
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.gridTest.myHorizontalScrollView
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at com.example.gridtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    ... 11 more
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gridTest.myHorizontalScrollView" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.example.gridtest-2/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.example.gridtest-2/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
06-03 11:37:43.688: E/AndroidRuntime(14781):    ... 21 more
```